# web3 - web3.utils.toHex zeros length

Tags: web3js, contract-development, truffle, bytes, hex

I'm trying to send 12 integer as bytes to a contract function. If I use

```
web3.utils.toHex(12)
```

the variable will become 0xc

The problem is that when contract function parses bytes, it reads uint256, so the result is revert.

How can I generate a hex with specific length? Like uint256, 128, 64, 32?

Edit: just tested manually and the variable I need is
0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c 
There must be a way to generate it somehow.

Comment: What do you want in the `bytes`? Do you want the ascii string `"12"`? If yes, then use `web3.utils.asciiToHex("12")`.

Comment: My goal is to pass integer 12 as an uint256 hex. toHex returns 0xc, but I want something like 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c - not sure if I put correct number of zeros, but passing this variable manually gave me correct result. And no, asciiToHex also didn't work, I need to pass integer, not string.

Comment: If your function takes `uint256`, then you can just pass 12. No need for any `web3.utils` function.

Comment: My function takes bytes.

Comment: So how exactly would "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c" help you here? If anything, you need the zeros at the end, not at the beginning (assuming you want to compare it to a string or something like that).

Comment: I think this question is somehow related to [your previous question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/74478/web3-utils-tohex-but-combined-hex-concat), am I right? I initially answered it, but then deleted my answer because it didn't seem to be exactly what you wanted (you might be able to see the deleted answer, depending on your privileges). And now that I look at both questions, I think that what you really need is function [`web3.eth.abi.encodeparameters`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-abi.html#encodeparameters).

Comment: My function reads bytes, grabs it and tries to turn it into uint256, so it reads 32 bytes. If I pass 0xc it reverts, otherwise if I pass 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c it doesn't show any error and if I read variable it shows 12, so it works correctly. But the clue is I'm passing it manually. 

YES! encodeparameters worked like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried casting a `bytes` variable with the contents of `"0x00000000....c"` into a `uint256`? It won't give you `12`!

Comment: And by the way, in Javascript (as in any other programming language), `0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c  == 0xc == 12`, so it won't make any difference which of them you use. If you encapsulate them with quotes or with double quotes, thus turning them into strings, then they are different of course.

Comment: It won't give 12? What should it give instead? I'm testing on remix and in one solidity function it glues my uints and string to one bytes 0x large chain and then other function splits that chain to individual variables put previously in the correct way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple you use [padLeft](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-utils.html#padleft). So first you turn your hex into string then pad the length that you want ( for example uint256 is 32 bytes so you need to pad 64 characters). Then from that string you convert it back to hex